# Why is my stylesheet applying to all my ejs files?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a nodeJS application using Express, MongoDB and EJS template view engine. I have created my server.js file which creates the server. I have created a separate header.ejs file which I will be including in my other ejs files (like index.ejs, about.ejs, contact..ejs, etc.). However when I create a stylesheet for only header.ejs file the styles are being applied to all the ejs file (index.ejs, about.ejs, etc.) 
I have placed my header.ejs file in the ./public/partials/ folder and the stylesheet is in ./public/assets/ folder and my index.ejs file is in the ./views/ folder.

I have used app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")) in the server.js file and /assets/style.css for index.ejs and /assets/header.css for header.ejs file.

> Server.js

```
app.set('view engine' ,  'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(employeeController);
```

> employeeController.js

```
router.get('/employee' , function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});
```

module.exports = router;

> header.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/header.css">
<h2>Company Logo</h2>
```

> index.ejs

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css">
 <% include ../public/partials/header.ejs %>
  <h2>Please Enter the New Employee Information</h2>
```

When I put h2 {color: indianred;} in the header.css file the color of  even in the index.ejs file changes even though header.css is linked only to header.ejs.

i want only the  of header.ejs to change. 
How do i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

As you are including `header.ejs` into `index.ejs` the `css` also gets added. That is the reason you are getting this issue.

To overcome this issue add a `class`/`id` to `h2`,

```
<h2 class="h2_css">Company Logo</h2>
```

or,

```
<h2 id="h2_css">Company Logo</h2>
```

Now add your `css` like this,

```
h2.h2_css {color: indianred;}
```

or

```
h2#h2_css {color: indianred;}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of adding classes and id's but I thought if there was a way I could do it without those for it would be better because the content of my header and footer ejs files will not having anything much so I did not want to use classes or id's. But thanks a lot for your advise.